# Getting data in rows from a 2D array in C/Objective C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

It's quite a simple question, yet I cannot find an answer that works.

Take the following 2D array: `int grid[4][4]`. I could fill it with integers, so that visually, it could look something like:

`1,0,0,5,0` `0,0,0,6,7` `3,0,0,0,7` `2,0,0,0,9` `4,0,0,2,0` (each segment a new row)

Now, what if I only wanted the data of one row, to be given as a standard array? The way I would of thought to do this would be: `grid[0]`, which would give me 1,0,0,5,0.

However, this does not seem to work. Can anyone tell me how I can extract rows of data? Here is a code example

```
int grid[4][4];

//Add in some numbers, e.g.
grid[0][3] = 5;

//Get the first row
int* row1 = grid[0]; //I'm not sure about this
```

For instance, this example should set "row1" to "0,0,0,5,0"

I have the feeling I'm doing something awfully wrong here...

There is no error message, but it just gives "row1" a random string of integers instead, which are definitely not correct.

Comment: Your `grid` is uninitialized, so it will print a random set of integers (of course). Try `int grid[4][4] = {{0}};` :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, in an array declared `int grid[4][4]`, you can only store four lots of four elements (sixteen total).

Your array, `{ 1,0,0,5,0 }, { 0,0,0,6,7 }, { 3,0,0,0,7 }, { 2,0,0,0,9 }, { 4,0,0,2,0 }` is actually an `int [5][5]`.

What you're doing is *not* wrong; `row1` will be a pointer to the first item of `grid[0]`. If you wanted to print each element, that's a good start...

In a moment of clarity, you'll likely realise when I mention the word "loop"... You then need a "loop" to loop through each element of the row!

```
int *row = grid[0];
for (size_t x = 0; x < sizeof grid[0] / sizeof grid[0][0]; x++) {
     printf("%d, ", row[x]);
}
putchar('\n');
```

Comment: @parkgatedev You're welcome! If this turns out to be your favourite answer, please give it your "tick" of approval... :)